# SciPy curve_fit displays straight line and is not fit to the data

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a set of data to a CDF exponential function. However, I'm not sure what is going wrong either in my code or in the initial parameter guess, but it only creates a straight line. Data was imported from a CSV file.

```
#Plot Data
plt.figure(1,dpi=120)
plt.title("Cell A3")
plt.xlabel(rawdata[0][0])
plt.ylabel(rawdata[0][1])
plt.scatter(xdata,ydata,label="A3 Cell 1")



#Define Function
def func(t,lam):
    return 1 - (np.exp(-lam * t))

funcdata = func(xdata,1.17)
plt.plot(xdata,funcdata,label="Model")
plt.legend() 

#CurveFit data to model
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata,p0=(-0.64))
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
```

[Image of the graph I get with the initial data and the straight line that the curve_fit gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRraJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fit correctly such a simple exponential function of this kind :

y=( 1 - (np.exp(-lam * t)) ) * scale

to the data because the shape of this function is far to the shape of the data in the range of 0<t<5.

Better consider a function of the logistic kind, For example :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Think about your data and your function. ydata is quite a large value. What is the maximum value of

```
def func(t,lam):
    return 1 - (np.exp(-lam * t))
```

I think you will find the max of the function occurs as lam approaches infinity, the function approaches 1. How can a function with max value == 1 fit data in the 1000s? If you want to be able to scale beyond 1, you need more parameters in your function. Try with

```
def func(t,lam,scale):
    return ( 1 - (np.exp(-lam * t)) ) * scale
```

and see if scipy is able to better fit the data.

EDIT:
I mananaged to get that to work, however, you aren't even plotting the optimum parameters. To do that, see my code with simulated xdata and ydata:

```
#Plot Data
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def func(t,lam,scale):
    return ( 1 - (np.exp(-lam * t)) ) * scale

xdata = np.arange(25.)
ydata = func(xdata, 1.12, 2000.)

plt.figure(1,dpi=120)
plt.title("Cell A3")
plt.xlabel(rawdata[0][0])
plt.ylabel(rawdata[0][1])
plt.scatter(xdata,ydata,label="A3 Cell 1")

#CurveFit data to model
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata,p0=[0.5, 1000.1])
plt.plot(np.arange(25),func(np.arange(25), *popt),label="Model")
plt.legend()
```

outputs:
[image: Optimized curve_fit]